# Typed form group, empty array interpreted as 'never'

Tags: angular, typescript

Why is empty array interpreted as `never` when using Angulars' `NonNullableFormBuilder`?

```
public form = this.fb.group({
    item: [[]],
});
```

And then:

```
this.form .patchValue({
      item: someValue,
});
```

I receive: `Type 'SomeType[]' is not assignable to type 'never'.`

How to make it work?

Comment: I don't know the `NonNullableFormBuilder`-API but `public form = this.fb.group({
    item: [[] as SomeType[]],
});` should work

Comment: should be noted this always happens in typescript whenever you provide an empty array the implicit type inferred is `never[]` (rather than expected `any[]`) until you cast it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's due to the definition of `group()`

```
export abstract class NonNullableFormBuilder {
  abstract group<T extends {}>(
      controls: T,
      options?: AbstractControlOptions|null,
      ): FormGroup<{[K in keyof T]: ɵElement<T[K], never>}>;
}
```

Which can be narrowed down to :

```
function foo<T>(t: T): T {
    return t;
}

const a = foo([]);  // never

const b = foo([] as Array<number>); // number[]
```

The constant empty array is inferred as `never[]`. Casting your array will fix the issue for you.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcA8AVRBTAHlbMAEwGdEBvAXwD4AKKALkQwEomtyBYAKET8QBO2KCAFIoAbh6UePCAhJREAQ0QBeZKloBtALosp3APRH%20iAHoB%20Wd3lhFiAEbrNcHbpVkAggIHKAnmhgIAC2jtgC1AY8JmZWQA)

Comment: as far as I know `[]` should not be considered a `null`? `[]` is a normal object, just without values stored

Comment: Please see my edit, it's a totally different reason.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you should try setValue() instead of patchValue().

```
this.form.setValue({
  item:someValue
});
```